# Python Closing Camera (CV) without closing my script

Tags: python, camera

I'm trying to make a script that makes some pictures with a USB webcame and store them in a directory. Those photo's are later used for Face Recognition. Everything works fine but the camera keeps buzzy so I cant use Face Recognition or make more pictures from a other user. The camera closes when I quit the script but I dont want to reopen it.

Code:

```
import cv2.cv as cv    
import cv2
    def fotos():
            print "Vul de naam van de nieuwe gebruiker in"
            print "Dit Proces kan een aantal seconden duren.\nBlijf in de camera kijken tot het menu weer verschijnt."

    Naam = raw_input("--> ")
    directory = 'Fotos/'+ Naam + '/'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)

    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

    i = 0
    while (i < 50):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
        cv.SaveImage('Fotos/'+ Naam + '/' + 'pic{:>05}.jpg'.format(i), img)
        print("Fotos/" + Naam + '/' + 'pic{' + str(i) + '.jpg')
        if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
            break
        i += 1

    cv.DestroyWindow('capture') 
    menu()
```

How can I close the camera? It feels like im missing something easy.
I found .release in the documentation but when I try:

```
capture.release

AttributeError: 'cv2.Capture' object has no attribute 'release'
```

Comment: I don't currently have OpenCV installed, so i can't try your code. But have you tried `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: This is how all my CV programs end in python3
           `k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
            if k == 27:
                Cap.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break`

Comment: The destoryAllWindows() Is not working:( I keep getting the error that the device is buzzy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
del(camera)
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15752256)

Comment: @AlSweigart, this is joey's answer - it's definitely not part of the question.  It does need a proper explanation, though!

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.